# Stream filter for Date

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-stream, java-time

I have a list of custom objects, which have a `String` field to store the date.

I need to write a filter to fetch the list of custom objects based on the condition: if days between custom object date and current date is equals to 4 then return the satified object in list.

I tried to parse the custom object string date to `ZonedDateTime` in filter. But it's expecting the `try`/`catch` block. How to handle this case?

Code:

```
list.stream().filter(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currDate,
    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant((df.parse(stringdate).toInstant(),ZoneId.of("UTC"))) == 4)
```

Comment: This is something of a disadvantage to streams. You could make a helper method that 'handles' the exception.

Comment: Is `df` a `SimpleDateFormat`? If you have Java 8's `ZonedDateTime` available, there's no need to mix the old `java.util.Date` API, just use a `DateTimeFormatter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Not directly related, but instead of `ZoneId.of("UTC")`, you can just use `ZoneOffset.UTC` - [according to javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-), they're equivalent: *"If the zone ID equals 'GMT', 'UTC' or 'UT' then the result is a ZoneId with the same ID and rules equivalent to ZoneOffset.UTC"*

Comment: It seems that you can just use `LocalDate` / `LocalDateTime` instead of the Zoned one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try/catch in lambdas:

```
list.stream().filter(stringdate -> {
        try {
            return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currDate,
                    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(df.parse(stringdate).toInstant(),
                                            ZoneId.of("UTC"))) == 4;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }).collect(...);
```

What do to in case of an exception is up to you of course, the `return false` in this code causes the element to be filtered out. You can also have another method that does the parsing and exception handling which you call from the lambda.

Comment: Or just use a `DateTimeFormatter` instead of mixing two different API. Then, you don’t need a try-catch block…